# What could cause a web form to function improperly on a single mobile device?

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, webforms, zebra-scanners

So, we have several Zebra TC21 mobile devices that our employees use for inventory and picking purposes. We have developed a web form where they can enter in different attribute values and assign them to products. One of these attributes is a pair of XY coordinates, each getting its own text input field. When the user submits the form, the coordinates are updated across all devices.

The application works perfectly except for a single one of our Zebra devices. For some reason, this one device is unable to update the XY coordinates of any product. The rest of the form functions completely normally on the device and you receive a success message when attempting to update the coordinates, but if you check the same product on another device, the record is unchanged.

All of the devices have been set up the same way and are all on the same WiFi network, and the browser settings for all devices are the same. I am not sure how to troubleshoot this.

Here is the function for updating the coordinates:

```
function updateXY()
{
    var updXYResult=sendForm2('http://@var_form_action_url_@','updXY','@var_sw_webserver_mode_@','@var_ajax_file_name_@');
    //alert('result: ' + updXYResult);  //debug
    var ResultStatus=updXYResult.substr(0,2);
    var ResultMesg=updXYResult.substr(10,90);
    //alert('message: ' + ResultMesg);  //debug
    switch(ResultStatus){
        case "OK":
            //update good - refresh stock info
            //doGetItem(document.updXY.stock_no.value);
            alert("Ro-Co has been update sucefully");
            break;
        case "ER":
            alert(ResultMesg);
            break;
            default : alert("TRY AGAIN! :(");
    }
}
```

And this is the inut for the form:

```
<input type="number" name="y_loc" id="y_loc" size="2" maxlength="3" value="@var_y_loc_@" style="width: 20%;">-<input type="number" name="x_loc" id="x_loc" size="2" maxlength="3" value="@var_x_loc_@" style="width: 20%;">
<input type="button" name="submitXY" value="Update Ro-Co" onclick="updateXY();">
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know about this hardware but I'm somewhat surprised `sendForm2` result is a return value of what came from the network and not a promise. Does this thing have a synchronous fetch API?

Comment: What do you mean by "one device is unable to update the XY coordinates"?  The user can't set the inputs or the user sets the inputs but the data is not sent?

Comment: @Yogi The user can set the input but the data is not being sent, despite being given the sucess message